# Laravel checkbox validation (O or 1)

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I am validating a checkbox here a user must select only one.

```
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="checkboxes">Can Resume </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="canRes[]" id="checkboxes-0" value="1">
                    Yes
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cannotRes[]" id="checkboxes-1" value="0">
                    No
      </label>
  </div>
```

And on server side in controller method i am validating :

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::get(),
[
    'canRes' => 'required',
    'cannotRes' => 'required'

 ]);
```

The validation fails because one is checked and the other is `required` I want one to be checked. Either `cannotRes` or `canRes`.

How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a use of validation method [required_without_all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-without-all)

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::get(),
[
    'canRes' => 'required_without_all:cannotResume',
    'cannotRes' => 'required_without_all:canResume'

]);
```

Hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario you need to use same name for both `checkbox`. You can try this:

```
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="checkboxes">Can Resume </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="canRes" id="checkboxes-0" value="1">
                    Yes
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="canRes" id="checkboxes-1" value="0">
                    No
      </label>
  </div>
```

In your validation function you should use this rule:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
[
    'canRes' => 'required',    
 ]);
```